# `git flow release finish` non-interactively

Tags: git, command-line, git-flow

How I can use `git flow release finish` in a manner that doesn't ask for merge commit messages? The `-m` flag doesn't provide this, as I expected.

The goal of course is to be able to script this in such a way that doesn't require interaction.

Comment: Relevant git-flow bug: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/pull/287

Answer (score 42):

You can set the environment variable

```
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no

git flow release finish -m 'Merge Message' release_branch_name

unset GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT
```

It won't invoke the editor for when you merge.

If you switch to my fork [git-flow AVH Edition](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) you can set this option to only work for when you use git-flow.

Comment: note: use `unset GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT` to turn this off (at the end of your script because clearly if you're reading this question, you're trying to script git-flow)

Comment: The `-m` merge message is also required, or else the editor will also be presented. And it must be specified before the name of the release branch in the command line arguments.

Comment: Which version of git is this Abhi? The git documentation does not say you need the message flag: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge/#git-merge---no-edit

Comment: You can avoid having to unset GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT in many shells by only setting it for the duration of the command: `GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no git flow release finish -m 'Finished.' 1.0.0`

Answer (score 7):

I had trouble with the -m flag. However if you give a message without spaces, it worked. Must be a bug.

```
git flow release finish -m 'my_message_with_no_spaces' 1.2.3
```

Comment: I'm running into this too. `flags:FATAL the available getopt does not support spaces in options`

Answer (score 6):

I've finished doing it:

```
git flow release finish -m "New release:$releaseVersion" -T
$releaseVersion -S $releaseVersion
```

where `-m` is the commit message, `-T` is tag message and `-S` is squash commit. Now everything is going to work automatically :)

Answer (score 4):

`git flow` is (more or less) just a wrapper around `git` commands.  Pop open the `git-flow-*.sh` of your choice, copy the git commands, and then mess with them.  In this case, add `--no-edit` to `git merge`.  This approach kills two birds with one stone: you can just copy these lines into your automation script.

Comment: Love this approach! Makes the change permanent. I also added -m "" to the git-flow-release script to prevent tag messages being required

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no out-of-the-box way to achieve that with the current version of git-flow.

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release), the git command used to merge is

```
git merge --no-ff
```

and there's no way to pass the `--no-edit` flag to it.

A couple of things you could do:

- fork the project and insert this capability (possibly as an optional flag)
- propose it as a feature and wait for the dev to implement it

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `-m` flag to specify a tag message on the command line.

It is still possible for the merges to have conflicts, but the tag operation will not try to open an editor for the tag message.

```
git flow release finish -m "my awesome release" 1.2.3
```

https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments#git-flow-release-finish--fsumpkn-version

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `git flow`, but if it supports standard git flags, you can use the `--no-edit` flag to [avoid merge commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744469/877115) in an automated setting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get this works by this code:

```
export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no
git flow release finish "$newVer" -m "$newVer" -T "$newVer"
unset GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT
```