# Git asks for commit message when pulling from other branch

Tags: git, version-control, terminal

Our company git workflow looks like this: Every team member has there own branch and pulls from and pushes to a main branch called develop.

Whenever I go `git pull develop` git automatically opens up a texteditor (my beloved vim that is) and asks `Explain why this merge is necessary`.

Why is this and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is git prompting me for a post-pull merge commit message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744081/why-is-git-prompting-me-for-a-post-pull-merge-commit-message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this in [`git-merge`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

> --edit
>
> --no-edit
>
> Invoke editor before committing successful merge to further edit the default merge message. The --no-edit option can be used to
>   accept the auto-generated message (this is generally discouraged) when
>   merging an annotated tag, in which case git merge automatically spawns
>   the editor so that the result of the GPG verification of the tag can
>   be seen.
>
> Older scripts may depend on the historical behaviour of not allowing
>   the user to edit the merge log message. They will see an editor opened
>   when they run git merge to merge an annotated tag. To make it easier
>   to adjust such scripts to the updated behaviour, the environment
>   variable GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT can be set to no at the beginning of them.

And I solove it by adding `export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no` in my `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 3):

The `git pull` command is, by default, a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.  The merge will check if it is possible to 'fast forward', which just adds the commits from the branch being merged in to your branch; but when changes have been made on your branch it is often not possible.

In this case the merge will create a merge commit to accumulate the changes on the branch being pulled in with the changes on your branch.  This commit needs a message, which can be defaulted (with the --no-edit parameter) to something along the lines of 'merged  into '; but is generally viewed as less than helpful.  An editor is invoked to allow a meaningful message to be entered for the merge.

Regardless of whether or not you edit the message or use the default, the 'extra' commit is created and clutters the history as it is not a commit needed for the work you are doing on your branch.  It is there just to 'catch up' your branch with what has been happening on the other branch

An alternative that does not add unneeded commits to your branch is to use `git pull --rebase`.  This will allow you to catch up on the commits in the other branch, without the hassle of the extra commit.  Here is an article that discusses it in more detail: [pull with rebase](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html).