# git merge specifies wrong author

Tags: git, merge

I have a problem with latest version of git i compiled under cygwin.

At first, it displays editor to enter merge message. Previously, it went sailent.
And then commit author seems to be different from normal commit.

When I do manual commit, author is `User Name <username@email.com>`, but when I do merge author name is `Domain\username <username@username.machine.name.com>`

Is there a way to make merge to specify the same auther as for manual commit? What's happening?

**EDIT** I have name.name and name.email specified in global git config. it seems that new git merge doesn't respect those settings.

Comment: Do you mean you have *`user.name`* and *`user.email`* set?  IOW, did you set the right variables?

Comment: no, it's name.name and name.email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember there are 3 places config can be entered.

Do a

```
cd  (to the git project folder)
git config --global -l

git config --local -l

You may also have a `--system` config

git config --system -l
```

and compare the `user.name` and `user.email` in all outputs. They should probably only exists in the `--global` but maybe you have a strange on in one of the configs.

PS. You said you had a `name.name` and `name.email` I suppose that was just a typo? They should be `user.name` and `user.email`

**EDIT: After questioners reply**

If you have `name.name` and `name.email` run this to create the correct settings

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Then I would

```
git config --global --unset name.name 
git config --global --unset name.email
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have only a system config and I found that it has [name] section and there is name and email parameters there. So probably the problem is that wrong section name. But it works fine for manual commit still.

Comment: cat pathToRepo/.git/config could also show local configs

Answer (score 1):

Prompting for merge message is Git's new feature. See [Why is git prompting me for a post-pull merge commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744081/why-is-git-prompting-me-for-a-post-pull-merge-commit-message) here on SO.

To make sure your settings are correct, check output of this:

```
$ git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT; git var GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT
```

This both should be your preferred identification. If you don't override it in environment, it is taken from Git's configuration.

Also Git's configuration is hierarchical, so check if you don't override the preferred values in your repository's config (.git/config):

```
$ git config --file --get user.name; git config --file --get user.email
```

should be empty.

If your settings seems correct and merges still have the generic identification you don't want to use, consider [sending a bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728104/where-can-i-report-a-git-bug) to the developers.