# How can I stop git merge prompt message keep popping up everytime I do git pull?

Tags: git

Why do I see a git merge prompt message keep popping up everytime after I do `git pull` ?

I am **100%** sure that there is nothing is merging.

It so annoying, does anybody know how to stop it ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is git prompting me for a post-pull merge commit message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744081/why-is-git-prompting-me-for-a-post-pull-merge-commit-message)

Comment: ‘*I am 100% sure that there is nothing is merging.*’ How? Do you not have any un-pushed commits?

Comment: @Hexaholic : I tried every answer there. Nothing seem to work.

Comment: @rangerover.js Could you show us the output of `git status`?

Comment: If I do `git status` now, I will get
`On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: This is on my production server running Linux.

Comment: If I edit something on my local env, push it, and pull it from my production server again, I will get the git merge prompt again. :(

Comment: hmm...maybe you have the config `pull.ff` set to false (check it with [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why do I see a git merge prompt message keep popping up everytime after I do git pull ?

Because `git pull` is essentially a `fetch` followed by a `merge`, and the default behavior of `merge` is to automatically commit the result.

You can avoid the editor by supplying the `--no-edit` option, in which case you'll get an automatically generated message for your commit.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, this means a fast-forward merge was not possible. Usually this happens when there are commits in master that are not present in origin's master branch (or whatever branch you are pulling from/merging to)

In that case history, after the fetch done by git-pull, would look like the following:

```
                       origin/master
                       |
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E
              \
               +-- D'
                   |
                   master
```

To bring changes D and E into the local master branch, git needs to introduce a merge commit, M (which records the parents and solves potential merge conflicts), and that's why it's asking you for a messsage.

History after the merge looks like in the following graph:

```
                       origin/master
                       |
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E
              \         \
               +-- D' -- M 
                         |
                         master
```

This is the default behaviour as far as I can tell. However, [git-pull documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) says:

> The --no-edit option can be used to accept the auto-generated message (this is generally discouraged).

DISCLAIMER: I don't have git available right now to test it :(