# Git pull asks me to write merge message

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I pull from **my branch**:

```
git checkout mybranchSample
git fetch
git pull origin master
```

Then, Git gives me the following message:

> Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
>   especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch

[image]

And after entering a commit message, it merges `master` into my files. And even though I haven't worked on some files from `master`, it shows the files list in green when I type `git status`.

This issue is **not** happening with my colleagues, but me only.
What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Please don't use an image (especially a badly sized one) to show us some text.

Comment: "show files in Green" does not say much. It should title them somehow (modified, staged etc)

Comment: Were you trying to merge ```master``` to ```mybranchSample``` or just wanted an updated code in ```master```?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11744081/477476), but unfortunately can't be closed as such due to the bounty.

Comment: @Cactus Please try to read the question fully. If that Question answers the question then tell me >> why Only I am getting the error though all people have same content in git config file `Host gitserver User git Hostname 91.12.12.12 Port 22 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pratikj`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Update your master or update your branch?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Because the others supposedly don't work on their local master-tracking branch directly. Instead, they likely use topic branches as you should, too, in order to control their merges. This feature forces you to think about what you're doing, and it worked. If you can't come up with a good explanation for the merge, then you probably shouldn't merge. This is for the sake of your team and your future-self. If you don't understand, learn, don't dismiss. Read about the original intent of the feature [here](https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/SrePhcj6XJe).

Comment: Instead of offering a bounty why don't you remove the image and include the output of `git status`, you are far more likely to results with a question that has the relevant details

Comment: @AndrewC , please check question again. git status just shows Green Files came from remote branch.

Comment: 'Shows green files' isn't useful information

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`git pull` is basically two actions at once: `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` (unless you use `git pull --rebase`, in which case you can guess what happens).

The reason you're seeing this is because Git can't do a **fast-forward** merge, like it can most of the time. The reason for that is usually because you've `git commit`ted locally to the branch you're trying to pull, and now you need to merge the remote changes with your local ones.

It's also worth noting that Git pre-populated the merge message for you, so you don't really need to type anything. Just save and exit, and the merge should be complete. (Unless, of course, there are merge conflicts).

Comment: My main question is `Do I need to worry about it`? Will anything wrong happen if I still get the window and type some message?

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Nope, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha any idea why Only I am getting the error though all people have same content in git config file `Host gitserver
    User git
    Hostname 91.12.12.12
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pratikj`  ?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha , Hi could you please answer my question ?

Comment: This might sound silly, but I cant exit the nano session (the exit command just closes the command help prompt) for the message, how do you save the merge message and proceed?

Comment: @Skyler : Ctrl + O then Ctrl + X

Answer (score 33):

Linus Torvalds explains it best:

> Spreading the word about an upcoming 'git' UI change, since I'm
>   largely to blame.
>
> This change hopefully makes people write merge messages to explain
>   their merges, and maybe even decide not to merge at all when it's not
>   necessary.
>
> I've been using that git feature for the last few weeks now, and it
>   has resulted in my merges from submaintainers having various notes in
>   them (well, at least if the submainter gave me any). So I'm trying to
>   lead by example.
>
> But if you don't like explaining your merges, this might be annoying.
>   Of course, if you don't explain your merges, you are annoying, so it
>   all evens out in the end. "Karmic balance", so to say.

Source: https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/SrePhcj6XJe

Comment: `"But if you don't like explaining your merges, this might be annoying. Of course, if you don't explain your merges, you are annoying, so it all evens out in the end."`

Hah. Classic!

Comment: The source link is dismissed.

Answer (score 5):

If you were trying to merge `master` to `mybranchSample` branch, then this is perfectly normal.

Git merges `master` to `mybranchSample` (when you did `git pull origin master` from `mybranchSample` branch) and `commits` the merge changes for you (unless there is any conflict) and gives you the pre-populated message. You can just save and exit.

**BUT** If you were just trying to get the latest code from the remote `master` branch to merge with local `master` branch, then you should checkout out to `master` and then pull from `master`.

from you statement

> it merges master files into my files. And even though I havent worked on some files from master, it shows the files list in Green when I type git status.

I think you are trying to do the second one.

so, try:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is only happening to you is not that your config is different, but that the branch you're merging in is different.

The reason for the files in the diff that you did not change is that after a merge, the new commit has to parent commits: The commit you did last and the newest commit on master. The new commit contains *all changes/files*. So if you diff from **new** to **your last commit** you will see all the files as changed/added that were changed/added on master while your branch was out of sync with the master branch.

Comment: I realize this was 6 years ago, but I figured I'd ask and hope for the best. Could you possibly offer some advice on how to solve this? I'm afraid if I try to solve it myself I'll mess everything up. I'm trying to run git diff, but I don't receive any output when comparing commits

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an issue with the branches... The 2 possible scenarios I could imagine you're facing:

1)
You have a remote branch, `mybranchSample`, and you wanna work on it - you have nothing to do at the moment with the master branch (that is, you don't wanna merge your branch into master or vice versa). You say in your question

> When I take pull from **my branch** after fetch like ...

But what you do is `git pull origin master`, which pulls from **master**. Instead, you should be able, with git version >= 1.6.6, to checkout your remote branch using

```
git fetch
git checkout mybranchSample
```

---

2) You try to work on `mybranchSample` but wanna have the latest code from the master branch there. Then it makes sense that a merge might be necessary, as Anand S said.

Answer (score 3):

Just to try to give everyone a simple answer, and please correct me if I am not correct:

This seems to happen when you `git pull` after committing on the branch. Your local changes don't exist on the remote so it makes a commit to get everything synced.