# git pull tries to merge although there are no local changes

Tags: git

i have a bash script:

```
cd ~/www/myprj
pwd
git pull https://usr:psw@bitbucket.org/myusr/myprj.git 
git checkout branch2
git log --oneline -n 15 --pretty=format:'%h %ar [%ai] (%ae) %s' --date=short origin/branch2
```

which i used to run from a php script using:

```
<?php system("bash ~/private/pull.sh"); ?>
```

I used it to pull all changes from a remote bitbucket repository and updated development version of the project. However, since recently it stopped working. After trying to trace the problem and running the commands from the terminal I found that the `git pull` is trying to merge the latest commits although there are no local changes?

Any idea of how can I just force the `git pull` and ignore local changes? or is there any other way to pull the changes without merging?

i tried `git pull --no-edit` but it didn't help me

Comment: Adrian, it doesn't pull the latest commits from the remote repository

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526346/git-pull-asks-me-to-write-merge-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first on which branch you are when doing a `git pull`, in order to make sure the merge step is trying to merge the expected branch.

See also your `git config --local -l` to check how the branches are declared/merged.
Or if you have directives [like `git config core.autocrlf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreautocrlf), which could introduce local changes automatically.

Then, as a workaround/test, try and clone the repository again in a new folder, and see if the issue persist in that new cloned repo.