# Git merging branches

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I am trying to merge two branches into a single new branch, and all three branches have a single parent branch in common.

Two branches "feat1" and "feat2" are isolated and branched off from "dev" branch.
Now I want to create a new branch, called "next-release" from "dev", and merge "feat1" and "feat2".

What I did :

1. checked out to "next-release" and merged "feat1".
2. then merged "feat2".

At this point, I'm getting `"Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary..."`.

Am I doing it right?

To explain it better:

```
  dev
   |
----------------
|       |      |
feat1   feat2  next-release = feat1 + feat2
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have that on a git pull, do you? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36418799/6309)

Comment: It is correct that you get asked for a commit message when you end up with a merge commit. It is also correct that you end up being asked only for the second merge as the first merge will be a fast-forward which won't commit anything (unless you force it). So yes, you appear to be doing it right.

Comment: @VonC thank you for making that clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yes, your sequence is correct (provided you did create the integration branch from dev at the point where feat1 and feat2 were created (as it appears to be from your diagram): that way, the merge between feat1 and feat2 benefit from a common ancestor.

Second, the message is, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19085807/6309), a way for your editor called by Git to prompt for a merge message commit: once entered, that will complete the merge.