# git pull -X theirs requires MERGE_MSG editing in ubuntu but not in windows

Tags: bash, git, ubuntu

I have a bash script running on ubuntu and on windows: 

`git add -A
git commit -a -m "auto l"
git pull -s recursive -X theirs
git push origin`

In ubuntu the second to last line causes nano editor to pop up requesting naming or editing of MERGE_MSG. Windows no such problem. EDIT WINDOWS TOO Rerunning the script 2 more times solves problem but that seems sloppy. Exists another -m 'auto' I must add during pull or what?

Comment: seems like just needs --no-edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744081/why-is-git-prompting-me-for-a-post-pull-merge-commit-message#11744469

Answer (score 2):

Check if (on Windows) you do have a `pull.rebase` setting set to `true` (as [I recommend since Git 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309))

```
git config pull.rebase 
git config rebase.autoStash
```

That would means Git on Windows would rebase your local commits on top of `origin/yourBranch`, instead of trying to create a merge commit between `origin/yourBranch` and `yourBranch`.

But if you don't, and if that must create a merge commit, then, as noted by the OP, [**`git pull --no-edit`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---edit) can can be used to accept the auto-generated message (this is generally discouraged, but here useful).

Comment: git config --get is empty for both. Can I really re-base if 2 computers are automatic and one will edit files each auto computer changes also?

Comment: infact i don't think those exist

Comment: @ran8 you can set those configs up: `git config --global pull.rebase true` and `git config --global rebase.autostash true`

Comment: @ran8 The rebase can be automatic if there is no conflict.